# How to have two separated contacts with same email address?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Using Exchange 2013 and Outlook 2013, I need to have two separated contacts with same email address. What I've seen is once I create a contact with an email address, for the second contact (even though I choose to create a new contact instead of update the existing one) Outlook merges two contacts details.
Now the question is, is this doable at all? Can I have two or more contacts sharing same email address but having isolated details?

In fact, I'm using ews managed API to do this programmatically, but that doesn't matter because same thing happens by using Outlook directly.

Update: Looks like Outlook 2013 by default links contacts with the same email address. And according to this post [Office Community](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/284948) the only way to stop that is changing a registry key!
Now I wonder if it's possible to stop this from Exchange side.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Duplicated detection in Outlook in the Option-Contacts, in EWS it shouldn't be doing any duplicate detection, if the contact is in the GAL then it will resolve it to the GAL address. Generally in this case your creating a OneOff Email address for a contact you can ensure that unique by using a different display-name when your create the contact. eg

```
        Contact contact1 = new Contact(service);
        contact1.GivenName = "Fred";
        contact1.Surname = "Smith";
        contact1.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1] = new EmailAddress("fred smith1", "fsmith@domain.com");
        contact1.Save();
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: That's true. using EWS there isn't any duplicate detection. It creates two contacts but the issue is it aggregates the data for addresses and phone numbers, etc. So you would see e.g. Fred Smith and Daniel Smith who are using a shared email address, with two phone numbers against each

Comment: I don't think you can control that aggregation as far as I know, if you can it would be a client setting I suspect